# Ionic/cordova: how to add push capability with fastlane or xcodebuild?

Tags: ionic-framework, xcode8, ios10, xcodebuild, fastlane

I have an Ionic project which uses Ionic.io push messaging. It is built with Fastlane and deployed through HockeyApp.

Since upgrading to Xcode 8 push notifications no longer work on iOS 10.

I have an entitlements file containing the push entitlement and it is added to the xcode project file with a ruby script, see https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/6544

When I build the project with Fastlane push still doesn't work. When I open the project file in Xcode and look at the capabilities section it shows a checkmark in "Add the push notification entitlement to your entitlements file" but shows an error in "add the push notification feature to your app id".

If I press "fix" and rebuild, push **does work**.

So my problem is:

I want to be able to get the push capability enabled correctly, only using Fastlane, xcodebuild, ruby or whatever, as long as it's only in the command line and allows my ionic project to be built cleanly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I managed to get it working by doing two things:

- I deleted all old provisioning profiles from xcode. This reversed the problem, so Xcode complained that the push entitlement was not added to my entitlements file, but there was a checkmark in "add the push notification feature to your app id".
- Next I changed the script to include the project file in the project itself. I have been informed by https://github.com/Azenet that probably, this is related to not using match from Fastlane.

Thanks to https://github.com/Azenet and https://github.com/hjanuschka for getting me 90% of the way.

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'xcodeproj'

name = ARGV[0]
projectpath = "../platforms/ios/" + name + ".xcodeproj"
puts "Adding entitlement push to " + name
puts "Opening " + projectpath
proj = Xcodeproj::Project.open(projectpath)
entitlement_path = name + "/" + name + ".entitlements"

group_name= proj.root_object.main_group.name

file = proj.new_file(entitlement_path)

attributes = {}
proj.targets.each do |target|
    attributes[target.uuid] = {"SystemCapabilities" => {"com.apple.Push" => {"enabled" => 1}}}
    target.add_file_references([file])
    puts "Added to target: " + target.uuid
end
proj.root_object.attributes['TargetAttributes'] = attributes

proj.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings.store("CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS", entitlement_path)
end
puts "Added entitlements file path: " + entitlement_path

proj.save
```

Comment: if .entitlements is still not set under targets, add `  target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings.store("CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS", entitlement_path)
        end` inside targets iterator.

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 10.1 and Cordova 4.5.5 I had to rewrite the script like this:

```rb
def enable_push_notifications()
  fastlane_require 'xcodeproj'
  fastlane_require 'fileutils'

  app_name = get_app_name

  puts "Adding Push entitlement to #{app_name}"

  proj = Xcodeproj::Project.open(File.expand_path("../platforms/ios/#{app_name}.xcodeproj"))

  attributes = {}
  proj.targets.each do |target|
    attributes[target.uuid] = {"SystemCapabilities": {"com.apple.Push": {"enabled": 1}}}
    puts "Added to target: " + target.uuid
  end
  proj.root_object.attributes['TargetAttributes'] = attributes

  FileUtils.cp_r(
    File.expand_path("./overrides/Entitlements-Debug.plist"),
    File.expand_path("../platforms/ios/#{app_name}/Entitlements-Debug.plist"),
    remove_destination: true
  )
  FileUtils.cp_r(
    File.expand_path("./overrides/Entitlements-Release.plist"),
    File.expand_path("../platforms/ios/#{app_name}/Entitlements-Release.plist"),
    remove_destination: true
  )

  proj.save

  puts "[OK] Added Push entitlement"
end
```

Here instead of creating `.entitlements` file I override two other files (`Entitlements-Release.plist` and `Entitlements-Debug.plist`) with the same content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```